# C Parser using lex and yacc

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex

I was fiddling with the code for an ANSI C parser given here http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html and here http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html.

Unfortunately, the code isn't working - I modified it a bit to make it print a message upon successfully parsing an input program, but the message is never printed, even if the input program is in C with no syntax errors. I'd be glad if anyone can help me out here.

EDIT:

Just to clarify - I was only testing a publicly available lex + yacc program on a simple input C program that prints "Hello World!". The links are present above. Please just open them to see the code.

Comment: You might want to post some code, as it's pretty hard to tell what might be wrong without it. Also, take a look at [ask].

Comment: Note that C parsers you can find on the net are typically [not correct](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/02/the-context-sensitivity-of-c%E2%80%99s-grammar-revisited/).

Comment: Downvoters: Please give a reason for downvoting in the comments.

Comment: @jpw The lex program and the yacc program are there in the respective links. Please open the links.

Comment: The problem, at least here on my side, the links don't open. This is the reason, why it is almost always better to include the relevant code in addition to the links.

Comment: With that grammar, you need to add symbol table handling to recognize type names properly.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Yacc file just checks that your input program is correct (by printing an error if not), but it does nothing else.

Add some semantic actions (some code to execute when a rule has been matched), between curly braces just after the rules. See http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_4.html#SEC11

You can start by printing something when a rule is matched, but if you want to build a C compiler, you'll have to build an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

**EDIT**

You also need to add a main method which calls the parser. Just add

```
void main() {
    yyparse();
 }
```

at the end of the yacc file.

The parser will read the inputs from stdin. So, if you're using Linux or MacOSX, you can type

```
./parser < helloworld.c
```

or for Windows

```
parser < helloworld.c
```

Actually, the parser prints the input file if it is correct.

Comment: I actually did add semantic action to the yacc program given in the link. The `start` rule is `translation_unit`, and hence I wrote `printf("Syntax Correct!\n");` in curly braces after the rule. But when I did this and executed the program, it never printed "Syntax Correct!" for any input. This is what I was talking about in my question. The print code is never executed. I don't understand why.

Comment: Just copy-paste the yacc and lex programs given in the links to newly created yacc and lex files, add the semantic action I mentioned and try running them on an input C program that you know is syntactically correct.

Comment: so, Do i need to run these commands `yacc -d grammar.y`  `mv y.tab.c grammar.c` and then compile `grammar.c`? which is nothing but `parser`